# PGSQL seems to ignore param passed in

Tags: postgresql, function

Issue: If I call with valid parameter I get a whole lot of results I should not.

So, while it seems aware of parameters, they're not used as I would expect.
If I call with no parameter at all I get an error there is no such function, so that's expected.
If I call with valid parameter I get a whole lot of results I should not.

So, while it seems aware of parameters, they're not used as I would expect.

Workaround: I can be redundantly specific with a where clause, but I know there's something I'm missing here. I expect to pass a territory id and get ONLY results for that territory id. I'm getting all territories right now.

`select * from by_territory_id('TER-123') where territory = 'TER-123';`

Of course I want to simply do the following, as that is what wrapping this in a function is for:

`select * from by_territory_id('TER-123');`

If anybody can see what is wrong here please point it out? The parameter is supposed to be used in the WHERE clause of this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION by_territory_id (territory_id char)
RETURNS TABLE (customer_id char, territory char, scan_id int, scan_status iol.consignment_audit_scan_status) AS $$
    select distinct con.customer_id, cus.primary_territory stm_territory, cas.id, cas.status
    from iol.consignment con 
    join iol.products prod 
    on con.description = prod.description 
    join iol.customers cus
    on con.customer_id = cus.customer_id
    left join iol.territories_and_roles tr
    on cus.primary_territory = tr.territory_id
    left outer join iol.consignment_audits_scan cas
    on cus.customer_id = cas.customer_id
    where prod.lvl3_id in ('PREMIUM', 'STANDARD')
    and tr.role = 'STM' and cus.primary_territory = territory_id
    order by cas.id
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

EDIT: Two down votes saying I'm not clear enough at the point of this edit. All the same, the one answer is correct. I hope it is okay that I really just needed eyes on this and I believe somebody else will run into the exact same issue, so rather than expand on the above I'm going to leave it be because the issue was indeed the name of my parameter (and PG gave no complaint or indication).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like one of your tables has a column named territory_id, and that is what is getting invoked by you unqualified reference.  You can qualify it with the function name:

```
and tr.role = 'STM' and cus.primary_territory = by_territory_id.territory_id
```

Or better yet change the spelling of the parameter so that it is distinct.

Comment: I can't believe I did that. I changed the variable name, but I had no idea you could use the function name like that. Thanks so much for the info!